# How to convert an IP to a u32 and back?

Tags: rust, ip, ip-address

I am wondering how to convert an IPv4 address from and to `u32`:

```rust
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;
let addr = Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1);
...
```

Comment: Updated title, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are conversion implementations available, [`From<Ipv4Addr> for u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html#impl-From%3CIpv4Addr%3E-1) and [`From<u32> for Ipv4Addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html#impl-From%3Cu32%3E), so you can use `.into()` or `T::from()` to swap between them.

```
let addr = Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1);
let addr_u32: u32 = addr.into();
let addr = Ipv4Addr::from(addr_u32);
```